# How to create directory in APEX Oracle directly?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How to create a directory directly through SQL Commands menu directly in APEX Oracle? I tried creating one, it said insufficient privileges. I tried granting myself permissions, that resulted in the same error.

Comment: Have you asked your DBA to grant your user permission to create directories?

Comment: @JustinCave i am the only one who works on this app that i am currently working on

Comment: Who is the DBA?  Or are you saying that you installed the database on your local machine?  If that’s what you did, you can connect as the DBA and issue the grant

Comment: @JustinCave ive been working on an app directly in APEX Oracle, the database is there. I have locally installed database that hasnt been touched yet. I want to create a directory cuz i got to the part when i need to upload photos, but there isn't any way to create a directory directly in APEX Oracle. Is there any way i can connect the local database with the one i have in my APEX Oracle workspace?

Comment: If you created a workspace on apex.oracle.com, you can't create a directory object.  An Oracle directory points to a location on the host's file system and you don't have access to the host's filensystem.  You can create a file upload control to upload images into the tables in your application.

Comment: @JustinCave is it possible to download my own oracle database, ords, apex oracle, export the database schema and the application itself and continue from then on locally? if so, how can i do that? sorry for asking such technicalities, but i just recently started working with apex oracle and i am kinda clueless about these stuff lol

Comment: note that in general it is not advised to push static content to the web server using APEX, as the web server (that the user interacts with for static content) and database server (where APEX runs) are often *not* on the same host and 2) it is a potential security issue to make static directories on the web server available over the network  to the database server. Content uploaded through APEX is generally stored as BLOB objects *in* the database. Even if you copied out through a `directory` object that pointed to a network share, you'd have to store it as a BLOB in the database first.

Comment: You can certainly export your APEX application, your data services, etc. and load that data into a local database.  Of course, that assumes you have installed APEX in the local databasr, that you have installed a web server, etc.

Comment: @pmdba i dont plan to use the app in commercial use, it's just something i do for practice as a side project to learn apex more... but this directory thingy kinda screwed me so i dont see any other possible workaround other than installing everything locally...

Comment: @JustinCave lovely, then i am on it asap...

Comment: Also note that creating a directory *object* in the database doesn't create a *directory* in the file system. The file system directory must already exist where the database can see it. There is no way for APEX to interact directly with the file system of the web server or database server.

Comment: @pmdba i already know that. i have some experience in working with directories, but tnx for the heads up!